# Need to update/remove a list of values based on user's request

Tags: java, hibernate, list, cookies

I have a list of names that are to be retrieved from database and shown to user, then user would be able to edit them or leave them unchanged.

I am wondering how I should implement it to compare the new values with retrieved ones.

Lets say values are as following

```
  ID Value
  -------- 
  1  Jack
  2  Daniel
  3  Allen
  4  Nick
```

Once they are shown to user, he/she changes them as following

```
  ID Value 
  --------
  1  Jack Moore  //moore is added
  2  Alex        //value is totally changed
  3             //value is erased
  4  Nick        //unchanged
```

Now I need to update the value of first two items, remove the third item from database as its new value is blank and leave the last item unchanged.

```
@Entity
Class Names {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private long id;
   private long value;
   ...
} 

@Entity
class Students {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;
  @ManyToOne
  private Names name;
```

}

I could think of putting the list of values in the cookie and compare the values of cookie with the new values but not sure if thats the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: If `ID` is the primary key, you can just over write the records with new values in DB. For the null/blank value you might need a separate check if you want to delete the record itself.

Comment: @NikhilTalreja I know but question is that should I use cookie to compare the submitted values with the persisted values?

Comment: Cookies are not necessary here. Just bring back the entire updated list back to your server code and over write the records in DB. Handle the delete separately as needed.

Comment: @NikhilTalreja I've suggested cookies to avoid sending multiple update requests to the database.

Comment: In your example, 75% of the records have changed. If you think this will be the case most times, why spend time in finding whether an update is required or not and then have to update eventually at least 3/4th of the time? Cookies are not meant to be used in such scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have updated list of names as:

```
    List<Names> namesList = new ArrayList<Names>();
    Names name = new Names();
    name.setId(1);
    name.setValue("Jack Moore");
    namesList.add(name );

    name = new Names();
    name.setId(2);
    name.setValue("Alex");
    namesList.add(name );

    name = new Names();
    name.setId(4);
    name.setValue("Nick");
    namesList.add(name );
```

Send this list directly to JPA session and call update. The update will automatically take care of creation/updation/deletion operations.

```
    session.update(namesList);
```

So, finally you will see only below records in your db table:

```
ID Value 
--------
1  Jack Moore 
2  Alex       
4  Nick
```

Comment: it is not possible as this entity is a member of another entity